# How R class are handled inside aab format (android app bundle)?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

I have a native app (I mean compiled in ARM) made in Delphi. This app was working pretty fine in Android32 with apk package. But now I want to migrate to android 64 and then use instead aab format but when i do so and when i run the app i receive the error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f04001d type #0x1c` **is not valid.** as it's a native app I must generate manually the `R class`, i do so like this

1. i use aapt.exe to create the R.java
2. then with javac I Compile the R.java into R$ classes
3. and finally I Build a classes.dex that include the R$ classes

I do 2 times this process, one time to build the android32 dex and SO library and another time to build the android64 dex and SO library

At the end I build the aab file using the bundletool-all-0.10.3.jar

What did i miss? why with apk my process is working pretty fine but with aab it's failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dex file must be the same for 32 bits and 64 bits, so you should have a single classes.dex and a single resource table (resources.arsc) to generate.

Also the AAB uses a resource table in a different format, which must be generated with aapt2, not aapt. See 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build for all the details.

Comment: thanks was that! i need to use aapt2 instead of aapt (https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27606)

Comment: Loki, did this solution work? Would you mind sharing your script as I’m trying to solve the same problem and having trouble refining my script to work correctly?